# Package showlabels and option final with equations

Tags: equations, amsmath, showlabels

I've the following problem with the `showlabels`-package: Using it with the `amsmath`-package, it ignores the option `final` for equations. The labels are still shown in the document.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[final]{article} 

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{showlabels}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{equation}
EI \cdot w'' + F \cdot w = 0 
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\caption{}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SE! With recent MikTeX I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Are you really just using this above code? Please clear your auxiliary files and check again. If this problem persists, please add `\listfiles` to your code and show us the version numbers of the used packages.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on TL either

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved with upgrade of showlabels package.